# Do I have to pass component into stack navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am doing a simple chat React Native (0.59) app for practicing purpose. But `App.js` constantly threw `Null is not an object` error. Then I commented out all components and just leave a createStackNavigator and createAppContainer. Here is the `App.js`:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 * @lint-ignore-every XPLATJSCOPYRIGHT1
 */

import codePush from "react-native-code-push";
import Chat from './src/components/Chat';
import Event from './src/components/Event';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

//create the navigator
const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  //Event: { screen: Event },
  //Chat: { screen: Chat },
});

//export it as the root component
export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

There still is an error of

```
Requiring module "App.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Properties can only be defined on Objects`
```

What is missing here?

Here is the `index.js`

```
/**
 * @format
 * @lint-ignore-every XPLATJSCOPYRIGHT1
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: can you post your codes of event and chat components?